# Perl Message::Stack example

Tags: perl, data-structures, perl-module

I am using Perl to try to implement an example for the [`Message::Stack`](http://search.cpan.org/~gphat/Message-Stack-0.22/lib/Message/Stack.pm) module from CPAN.

I get the error

> Can't locate object method "new" via package "Message::Stack" at stack.pl line 3.

```
my $stack = Message::Stack->new;

$stack->add(Message::Stack::Message->new(
  msgid     => 'something_happened',
  level     => 'error',
  scope     => 'login_formm',
  subject   => 'username',
  text      => 'Something happened!'
));

# Or... for those that want to type less
$stack->add({
  msgid     => 'something_else_happened',
  level     => 'error',
  scope     => 'login_form',
  subject   => 'password',
  text      => 'Something else happened!'
});

# ...
my $errors = $stack->for_level('error');
# Or
my $login_form_errors = $stack->for_scope('login_form');
$login_form_errors->for_subject('username');
print "Username has ".$login_form_errors->count." errors.\n";
```

Please let me know which object I need to load.

Comment: Did you read the complete error?  Didn't it tell you what you need to `load`?

Comment: did you `use Message::Stack;` ?

Comment: I get only the following error: Can't locate object method "new" via package "Message::Stack" at stack.pl line 5.

Comment: Yea when I try use Message::Stack I get the error as Can't locate Message/Stack.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at stack.pl line 4.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at stack.pl line 4.

Comment: then you need to install the module. You can use the `cpan` tool on the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure that what the message *actually* says is

> Can't locate object method "new" via package "Message::Stack" (perhaps you forgot to load "Message::Stack"?) at stack.pl line 5.

So, did you forget?

And later, when you actually try to load it using

```
use Message::Stack
```

and it tells you

```
Can't locate Message/Stack.pm in @INC
```

doesn't it occur to you that it's not found because it isn't there, and needs installing?